# Central Admin Pages showing a 404 Error

Tags: 2010, central-administration

I have an issue where I am getting a 404 error for some of the central admin pages but others work fine.  Here are the pages that give a 404 that I have identified so far:

http://admin.portal.acme.local/security.aspx
http://admin.portal.acme.local/configurationwizards.aspx
http://admin.portal.acme.local/upgradeandmigration.aspx
http://admin.portal.acme.local/backups.aspx
http://admin.portal.acme.local/searchadministration.aspx
http://admin.portal.acme.local/searchfarmdashboard.aspx

Any ideas how I might go about resolving this?  I am really close to just re-installing SharePoint to ensure a clean slate but that feels like overkill.

Comment: Can you provide some history on the environment?  Was this a new install or an upgrade?  Did it previously work?

Comment: Did you use Firefox from remote server? Please check AAM for further information as well as give more information on deployment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen it where some of the application pages will become ungosted for lack of a better term when custom masterpages are applied to the central admin site and then removed. try opening the admin site up in sharepoint designer and checking out and then checking in each page that does not work.

Comment: This was an environment that had custom solutions including branding the central admin.  I guess that makes sense then to have to update the pages to use the default master pages and layouts.